# Bootstrap modal close issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ngroute

I am trying to work the bugs out of my `modal`. I am using `Bootstrap`, `Angular` and `ng-Route`. I recently noticed on `mobile` (and then on desktop) when I push the back button with the `modal` open it leaves a gray overlay and you cannot `click` anything. So the solution I found that partially fixes the problem is to add this script:

```
$(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function()  { // any time a modal is shown
      var urlReplace = "#/" + $(this).attr('id'); // make the hash the id of the modal shown
      history.pushState(null, null, urlReplace); // push state that hash into the url
    });

    // If a pushstate has previously happened and the back button is clicked, hide any modals.
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      $(".modal").modal('hide');
    });
```

This works great then the user `presses` the `back button` however when the user closes the `modal` by clicking outside of the modal or hitting escape the `urlReplace` remains in the `browser` address bar. **I want to get it to change back to the previous when ever the `modal` is closed.**

If that issue cannot be resolved I at least would like this other issue to be fixed which is this: When the user closes the `modal` by clicking outside or hitting escape the `urlReplace` remains in the `browser` address which is fine but when the user then goes to `click` a link in my `nav bar` it doesn't take them to the link it goes to a blank page with the  `urlReplace` still in the address bar and then I can `click` a link in the `nav bar` again and it will go to the proper link which I find strange not sure how to resolve this issue.

Any ideas or insights into this would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a handler to watch for the modal close event, then push a new history with the hash removed:

```
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function()  { // any time a modal is hidden
    var urlReplace = window.location.toString().split('#', 1)[0]
    history.pushState(null, null, urlReplace); // push url without the hash as new history item
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought something else weird was going on but it just needed to be fed the proper url on closing the modal and the links I click in my nav work normally now!